# android onLocationChanged never called

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

I've implemented code that should return present location.

First the code:

```
public static double[] getLocation(Context context) {
        double[] result;
        lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        MyLocationListener ll = new MyLocationListener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

        while(!hasLocation) { }

        result = ll.getResult();

        return result;
    }

    private static class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        double[] result = new double[2];

        public double[] getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(location.getAccuracy() != 0.0 && location.getAccuracy() < 100) {
                result[0] = location.getLatitude();
                result[1] = location.getLongitude();
                hasLocation = true;
                lm.removeUpdates(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    }
```

The problem is that all stopps on 'while' statement. WHen I've tried to debug this setting breakpoint on the first line in onLocationChanged() nothing happens, but Logcat was showing some logs like:

```
loc_eng_report_position: vertical_accuracy = 64.000000
DEBUG/libloc(1292): date:2011-08-11, time:10:51:03.372, raw_sec=1313052663, raw_sec2=1313052663,raw_msec=1313052663372
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while(!hasLocation) {} is blocking your application from doing anything. You'll either need to deal with the location in the callback onLocationChanged, or you'll need to start the location manager a lot earlier and hope that you have a result by the time you need it. You can't busy-wait for the answer.

Comment: I wanted to wait with thread for getting location and after that return the result. Should I move requestLocationUpdates() to separate thread?

Comment: Ok, I moved it to separate thread with Looper. Now it's working. There's still a problem with removing updates. The GPS icon is disappearing too slow. Don't know why. Anyway, thank you for suggestions :-)